# What do these icons in Xcode 4 stand for?

Tags: xcode4

I've never seen these before, but what are the little 'A's and 'M's next to the filenames in the file browser for?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let me guess from the knowledge of SVN -

`A` => newly added file.
`M` => modified an existing file.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

this in relation to Source Control (git or Subversion)

check this page

[Save and Revert Changes to Projects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Save_and_Revert_Changes_to_Files/ManageChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH13-SW1)